# How to get the Return key on android keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

Is there a any way through which we can get Return key on android keyboard?

Comment: define "get" - you mean listen for when it is pressed?

Comment: Return key like iphone on pressing that return key i want to remove the focus of edittext so that OnFocusChangeListner get call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to listen for particular keys you can do so by:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            //ENTER WAS PRESSED!
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

For a full list of keys please see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: ya i know, but i want some thing like this. i have 4 Edittext vertically when im in 4th Edittext and i close Keyboard then the focus of that 4th Edittext get changed and onfocuslistner get called